# Android ExpandableListView Hide Group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView and the user can go into the settings of the app to decide which groups to display in the list. How can I make a particular group not be displayed? I've tried setVisibility(View.GONE), and that still leaves a space where the group was as well as the group indicator.

Can I make a group in my ExpandableListView not display and not leave a blank space where it was?

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at the Filter class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html It's a filter for ListViews, showing only what the filter matches, might be the answer to your problem.

Comment: It looks like the Filter class can only be used with EditTexts. Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't tested this but I'm sure you could ignore the edit text values and filter by something else in the performFiltering(CharSequence filter). For example iterate over your groups and add only the ones you want to the filter results.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be, **not to change the view**, in this case ExpandableListView. Instead, deal with the issue at the underlying data level. For example, with each group have an indicator, indicating whether to include or not to include that group. And then, only show groups that have their indicator as "show".